# Why load shared library from remote in module federation?

Tags: webpack-module-federation

[image]
[image]
In Module Federation example

https://stackblitz.com/github/webpack/webpack.js.org/tree/master/examples/module-federation?terminal=start&terminal=.

Why load shared library from remote in module federation?

Shared libraries should not be loaded from host for performance？

Answer (score 0):

Remove eager:true from  webpack module federation plugin config.

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTYFW.png)

Make sure react is a peer dependency as well.